В чем разница между turtle.Turtle() и turtle. Pen()
Пока смотрел видеоуроки по черепахе, заметил очень интересную особенность : кто-то говорит, для того чтобы задать нашей черепахе переменную нужна команда переменная=turtle.Turtle(),а кто-то
переменная=turtle.Pen(). Так в чем же разница?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Lib/turtle.py#L3881

Разница только в названии.
import turtle


print(turtle.Pen == turtle.Turtle)
# True

